# Paypal express checkout -reference payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have small confusion on the Paypal express checkout whether is it possible to do the reference payment for a buyer who paid through a credit card without a billing agreement(we disable the billing agreement because if we enable then Paypal asks to create a new account).

I know that  in payment-Pro we can do reference payment without any billing agreement since it is limited for few countries we are unable to use it.

Note:our merchant account has activated to do reference payment.

Thanks
Az

Answer (score 1):

You can do reference transactions on any payment within I think 90 days of the original transaction date. As long as you are a Website Payments Pro customer, this option is available to you. Just be aware that you will get a CVV2 mismatch (neither you, nor Paypal can store this due to PCI compliance) and that is normal.